# WatchOS Navigating back to app from Map

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am using `WKInterfaceMap` in a WatchOS app.  I have "enabled" check to allow the user to go to the map app by tapping on the map.  However, there seems no way for the user to navigate back to the app without tapping home and then tapping on the app's icon.  The "back" button on the map app does not take you back to the app but to further mapping options.  Is there a way for a user to navigate quickly back to the app itself without having to seek out the icon again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that feature was added in iOS allowing a user to return directly to a previous app, there's no corresponding feature on watchOS (possibly due to the limited space for a title on the much smaller screen).

The only related improvement in watchOS 3 is the dock.  If the user placed your app in the watch dock, the user could more easily navigate back to it via the side button, instead of using the digital crown and hunting for the app icon.